# Can I configure one monitor landscape and one in picture mode at the same time?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, nvidia

At the moment I am running Kubuntu Lucid LTS on my desktop and have some relatively free time and was considering upgrading to Natty.

My biggest concern (as usual) is whether I will be able to use my video card in the way its configured now, preferably without hours of configuration pain. The pain mainly comes from me having two monitors and a single continuous desktop. One monitor is used in landscape and another in picture mode (rotated 90 degrees clockwise), both having different resolutions.

I remember spending hours of getting it configured when installing Lucid originally as I had to tweak `xorg.conf` settings manually dozens of times, `randr` didn't work, etc. etc. I finally ended up using closed source driver as it was the only one being able to achieve the setup. I also remember my colleague installing Maverick on the next week after the release; he couldn't get it working with closed source nvidia drivers because newer Xorg libs weren't supported (so he had to use Xorg libs from Lucid) and the open source drivers couldn't get the job done. Royal pain stories like this have left me with a very low expectations for Linux on desktop in general and new Ubuntu releases in particular.

I personally don't care which drivers to use as long as I can get the monitor setup working (no need for any 3D acceleration, it's my working machine). I have spent some time looking at forums/help/AskUbuntu, but I cannot find any decent page confirming whether Natty can achieve my desired setup as the noise/information rate is too high.

My video card is (quote from `lspci -vvv`):

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G86 [Quadro NVS 290] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: nVidia Corporation Device 0492
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 52
    Region 0: Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 3: Memory at f8000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at dc80 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fbd00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia-current, nvidiafb, nouveau
```

So can anyone advice whether nVidia dual-monitor, rotated-screen, continuous-desktop can be achieved in Natty/Kubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm using 11.04 with nVidia open drivers. I've got external monitor working out-of-the-box without any problems at all. Different resolution, extended desktop. Instead of using directly `xrandr` I'm using [`disper`](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/).

[image]

Comment: Thanks - just a clarification: by "open" you mean Nouveau? Also, do you know if you can rotate any screen?

Comment: `Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidia-current, nouveau, nvidiafb`; didn't try rotation.